# random effect required?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, zero-inflation

For my Bachelor-Thesis i want to model the international stocks of migrants from country $i$ staying in country $j$ in year $t$ in dependency of the minimal geographic distance between $i$ and $j$, their population sizes, their GDP and a couple of other values.

I created a dataset that looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   269951 obs. of  20 variables:

 $ popc               : int  0 0 0 7 14 14 18 17 20 50 ...

 $ orig               : Factor w/ 194 levels "100","101","110",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

 $ dest               : Factor w/ 194 levels "100","101","110",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

 $ year               : Factor w/ 46 levels "1970","1971",..: 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 ...

 $ nbhd               : Factor w/ 2 levels "distant","neighbour": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

 $ dist_mini          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

 $ popt_orig          : num  0.274 0.279 0.284 0.29 0.295 ...

 $ popt_dest          : num  0.159 0.163 0.166 0.17 0.174 ...

 $ gdpt_orig          : num  5 5.02 5.07 5.09 5.15 ...

 $ gdpt_dest          : num  5.46 5.55 5.61 5.62 5.59 ...

 $ comm_lang_spkn     : num  9.8 9.8 9.8 9.8 9.8 ...

 ...
```

I found out, that for count data usually a poisson-regression is adviced. Since only 10% of all possible relations are indeed established and the values of the dependent variable therefore contain many zeros i have to use a zero-inflated model.

Isn't it the case, that i would also have to implement a random effect? Would a random intercept for $i$ and $j$ be adequate? How would i have to handle the time variable?

Comment: This is a mixture of on- and off-topic. You question about the need fro a random effect is on-topic and the answer is probably yes but more details would help. The rest would be better on R-help or StackOverflow.

Comment: You clearly will have to account somehow for how the number of migrants from country x living in country y is related over time (clearly the number in one year will tell you something about the number in other years) - one way of doing that is some kind of random effect. Not sure what your modelled variable is - the total number of people (in which case something like a Poisson may make sense) or the percentage of the people living in a certain country (in that case Poisson does not make sense). The zero-inflated bit really depends, it could be that random effects already "explain" the zeros.

Comment: The values of the modelled variable `popc` represent the stock (not flow) of Forced Migrants from country $i$ staying in country $j$ in year $t$. Would a separate random intercepts for $i$ and $j$ or a single random intercept for an interaction term between $i$ and $j$ make more sense? Couldn't i account for "last years stocks" by defining a specific covariance structure?

Comment: A NON-zero-inflated poisson-regression however cant handle the zero values (due to the log-link?). I tried using `glmmPQL()` from the `MASS` package in R with a random intercept for each pairing of `orig` and `dest` and an autocorrelation structure of order 1 with `year` as time covariate and the `orig`/`dest` pairing as grouping factor. It only fits if i exclude all zero-observations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure now that in my case i would need a zero-inflated generalized linear mixed effect model with an random intercept for each pairing of $i$ and $j$ and a temporal autocorrelation structure of the forced migrant stocks also grouped by each pairing of $i$ and $j$.

Since there are no R functions capable of fitting a model like that (at least none that i found out about), i have to restrict my observation to only one year.